# Where is the implementation of the function `_PyIO_str_readline` on the C Python implementation?

Tags: cpython

On the question, [How is file implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792658/how-is-file-implemented) I learned how `open()` method is implemented, but I cannot find where the `_PyIO_str_readline` function used on its implemented is defined.

1. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html
2. https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=_PyIO_str_readline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you think, `_PyIO_str_readline` is a function, but actually it is just a global variable (of type `PyObject *`), which is declared [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/_io/_iomodule.h#L173):

```
extern PyObject *_PyIO_str_readline;
```

and defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c96be811fa7da8ddcea18cc7abcae94e0f5ff966/Modules/_io/_iomodule.c#L46):

```
PyObject *_PyIO_str_readline = NULL;
```

to be `NULL`, but as name suggest could by any string-object (i.e. unicode in Python3 or bytes in Python2).

`_PyIO_str_readline` is a kind of a cache (often referenced as "interned string" in CPython - see [`PyUnicode_InternFromString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_InternFromString)),  so every time `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs` is called with "readline" as method-name, the corresponding object must not be constructed anew.

`_PyIO_str_readline` is initialized in [`PyInit__io`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c96be811fa7da8ddcea18cc7abcae94e0f5ff966/Modules/_io/_iomodule.c#L761) to its actual value, using macro `ADD_INTERNED`:

```c
/* Interned strings */
#define ADD_INTERNED(name) \
  if (!_PyIO_str_ ## name && \
      !(_PyIO_str_ ## name = PyUnicode_InternFromString(# name))) \
      goto fail;

...
ADD_INTERNED(readline)
..
```

i.e. `_PyIO_str_readline` is an unicode-object with value `readline`.  Which `readline`-method is actually used, is resolved during the run time and depends on what `self` actually is.

Comment: Do you know where this variable is initialized with some value? Searching all source code, the variable is assigned nowhere.

Comment: @user I have added more info concerning it.