# Where is source of function read() when using "with open"?

Tags: python

I need to find where the return is called.

I found only function with empty body like this:

```
def read(self, __size: int = ...) -> bytes | None: ...
```

or this:

```
@abstractmethod
def read(self, n: int = -1) -> AnyStr:
    pass
```

Comment: For CPython, I think it's here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c96be811fa7da8ddcea18cc7abcae94e0f5ff966/Modules/_io/fileio.c#L780

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230925/where-is-the-implementation-of-the-function-pyio-str-readline-on-the-c-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792658/how-is-file-implemented

Answer (score -1):

The with statement is just a context manager that takes care of creating and releasing file descriptors.

```
with open(file) as fin
```

Is the same as

```
fin = open(file)
…
fin.close()
```

The details you are looking for are in the documentation for open